# Separate web application that does not get SAML authenticated when using Systainsys library and IIS

Tags: saml-2.0

I'm trying to set up a separate application on the default website that does not require SAML authentication to use.  The existing application works well, but when I add the new application under the default website and try to navigate to it, I get punted to the identity provider used in the default website.  Is  this possible?

I have tried modification of the default website web config to specify that the cookie is only for the "MemberPages" path but this does not work:

```
<federationConfiguration>
    <cookieHandler requireSsl="true" path="/MemberPages" />
    </federationConfiguration>
```

Comment: You need to provide significantly more detail...